# Link button click event to get popup

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-1.1

Need a advise. I have a page, main.aspx page. I need to add a link to the main.aspx page. So that when employees clicks on the link, I have to show the employee profile (profile.aspx) page as a pop up. In order to do this can I use link button. I am working on .NET version 1.1. when I use link button I could not find the postbackurl.

Comment: dotnet version 1.1? really? Your best bet is jquery I don't think ajax would help..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the NavigateUrl of your link button to the profile page, and set the Target to "_blank".

Or as @Anders suggested, use jQuery to display a flowing "in-page" window.